# mySQL update based on select from other tables

Tags: mysql

How can I update a relation table with this structure:

`- especie_id
- multimedia_id
- isCover`

to set `isCover` = 1

when there's a match on the results from this query:

`SELECT id as multimedia_id, substring_index(substring_index(pathURL, '.', -3),'.', 1) as especie_id
FROM multimedias
WHERE tipo_multimedia_id = 31`

Do I need an inner join?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do an `UPDATE` like this:

```
UPDATE table1
SET isCover = 1
WHERE (multimedia_id, especie_id) IN (SELECT id as multimedia_id, 
                                        substring_index(substring_index(pathURL, '.', -3),'.', 1) as especie_id
                                      FROM multimedias
                                      WHERE tipo_multimedia_id = 31)
```

Comment: You beat me to it.

Comment: Beautiful! :) 2644 row(s) affected Rows matched: 2644  Changed: 2644  Warnings: 0